# calling js function works only for the first time on jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

on jquery mobile web app I'm calling js function on close button. That js function close it's callers div parent.
That works fine, but problem is that I have multiple close buttons and this function works perfectly first time, 
after that onclick doesnt work. It doesnt enter into js function.

I tried to put js function at very bottom of my _`Layout.cshtml` page but it doesnt change anything.

update

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#closeTable').click(function () {
         $(this).parent().hide();       
    });

</script>

<div id="closeTable"></div>
```

Comment: Please share your code and tell us what you have already tried.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "p.s. js function is called using ajax to async. remove html div parent."?

Comment: yes, I've forgot about that, I'm also call one more js function using ajax, but that's irrelevant now, cause this close button stop working event when this function(async) is not called at all. Please forget about that function.

Comment: " I have multiple close buttons " do all buttons share the same ID? If this is in case use class instead. IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is originating from the fact that you're using an ID to add event listeners to. In your JS, you have this line:

```
$('#closeTable').click(function () { ...
```

This line attaches a `click` event handler to the `div` with ID `closeTable`. Since there can only be **one** element with this ID, once it's hidden the user can't click it again and so the function won't be executed again.

If you have multiple close buttons as you say, you should instead use a class selector to attach handlers:

```
$(".closeTable").click(function() { ...
```

This will instead attach a listener to every element with class `closeTable`. This means that when **any** of them are clicked the function will execute, so it will work multiple times.

Hope this helps.